# xpages: refresh the view when different user login

Tags: xpages

In a xpage, it requires user to login. After the user login, there is a view shows the information that belongs to the logged in user.

Please find the xpage code below for your review: (please note, the view in Lotus Client contains various columns e.g. UserName, UserID, etc., but in xpage, due to the user needs to login, so I do not display the user name in the xpage)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xp:view xmlns:xp="http://www.ibm.com/xsp/core">

<xp:viewPanel rows="30" id="viewPanel1" pageName="/BookVenue.xsp" viewStyle="width:700.0px">

<xp:this.data>
    <xp:dominoView var="view4" viewName="UserBookedVenueInfo">
    </xp:dominoView>
</xp:this.data>
<xp:viewColumn columnName="Venue" id="viewColumn1" displayAs="link">
    <xp:viewColumnHeader value="Venue" id="viewColumnHeader1" sortable="true">
    </xp:viewColumnHeader>
</xp:viewColumn>
<xp:viewColumn columnName="ReturnDate" id="viewColumn2" displayAs="link">
    <xp:viewColumnHeader value="Return Date" id="viewColumnHeader2" sortable="true">
    </xp:viewColumnHeader>
</xp:viewColumn>
<xp:viewColumn columnName="Remarks" id="viewColumn3" displayAs="link">
    <xp:viewColumnHeader value="Remark" id="viewColumnHeader3" sortable="true">
    </xp:viewColumnHeader>
</xp:viewColumn>
<xp:this.facets>
    <xp:pager partialRefresh="true" layout="Previous Group Next" xp:key="footerPager" id="pager1">
    </xp:pager>
</xp:this.facets>
</xp:viewPanel>
</xp:view>
```

About the view, I use formula to get the data

```
tmp:=@Name([CN];@UserName);
SELECT Form = "BookVenue" & UserName =tmp
```

When I preview the xpage in the browser (Internet Explorer), the view can display the relevant data. However, when I close the browser, I use another account to login, the view shows the previous user's information.

Please consider the following scenario, at the first time, I use tester A account to login, the view can show information related to tester A. Then I close the browser, and reopen the xpage, it requires me to login so I use tester B account to login, the view shows the information related to tester A. I close the browser and use tester C account to login, the view still shows the information related to tester A.

Suppose I use tester C account to login and the view still shows the information related to tester A. I do not close the browser. In the view, I change the formula to this:

```
SELECT Form = "BookVenue" & UserName = @Name([CN];@UserName)
```

I refresh the browser, the view shows the data related to tester C. Then I close the browser and use tester B account to login. The view displays the data related to tester C.

The strange thing is, when I change the formula and refresh the browser, the view shows the proper data related to the logged in user.

```
tmp:=@Name([CN];@UserName);
SELECT Form = "BookVenue" & UserName =tmp
```

Why the view "remember" the previous logged in user's information?
I always think if the user login to the xpage, then when the user close the browser, the connection between the user and the xpage is closed. (maybe my concept is not correct)

If I keep change the formula in the view respectively, the view can show the proper data related to the user.(I have no idea why this approach works.)

My question is how to refresh the view when different user login? I guess the problem is in the formula:

```
tmp:=@Name([CN];@UserName);
SELECT Form = "BookVenue" & UserName =tmp
```

and

```
SELECT Form = "BookVenue" & UserName = @Name([CN];@UserName)
```

However I search on the internet @Name([CN];@UserName) is correct to get the username. I also recreate the view and the xpage again but the result is the same. I still need to the change the formula in the view to refresh the view in xpage.

Would someone let me know my mistake please? Thank you.

Reference:

http://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSVRGU_9.0.0/com.ibm.designer.domino.main.doc/H_USERNAME.html

Comment: Do not use @Username in selection formula of the view.

Comment: Hello @FrantisekKossuth, thank you for your comment. May I ask a question please?  Why do not use Username in selection formula of the view? If not use it, is there any method I can get the user name in the view

Comment: I think this [post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32057349/notes-view-how-can-i-show-only-those-documents-which-are-under-the-users-name) explain why do not use @Username in selection formula of the view. Sorry for my question in the comment.

Comment: In short: SELECT of the selection formula is evaluated by the indexer task on the server and thus runs with server's privileges. For private views it's user's opening the view.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot use @Username in view selections (see comment above). 
Nevertheless you can achieve this by the following solution design:
- Create a view with a categorized column which displays the Username
- in The View Panel, add a "Filter by category name " calculated using session.getEffectiveUserName()

The XPage below uses a view named "view" with a "cat" field which contains the username to filter.

```
<xp:view xmlns:xp="http://www.ibm.com/xsp/core">
<xp:this.data>
    <xp:dominoView var="view1" viewName="view"
        categoryFilter="#{javascript:session.getEffectiveUserName()}">
    </xp:dominoView>
</xp:this.data>

<xp:viewPanel value="#{view1}" id="viewPanel1">
    <xp:this.facets>
        <xp:pager partialRefresh="true" layout="Previous Group Next"
            xp:key="headerPager" id="pager1">
        </xp:pager>
    </xp:this.facets>
    <xp:viewColumn columnName="cat" id="viewColumn1">
        <xp:this.facets>
            <xp:viewColumnHeader value="Cat" xp:key="header"
                id="viewColumnHeader1">
            </xp:viewColumnHeader>
        </xp:this.facets>
    </xp:viewColumn>
    <xp:viewColumn columnName="subject" id="viewColumn2">
        <xp:this.facets>
            <xp:viewColumnHeader value="Subject" xp:key="header"
                id="viewColumnHeader2">
            </xp:viewColumnHeader>
        </xp:this.facets>
    </xp:viewColumn>
</xp:viewPanel></xp:view>
```

Please be aware that using this solution all users still can access and read all documents (in theory). If you want to make the documents unavailable, you should implement reader fields. More information can be found here http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/lotus/library/reader-names/

Comment: With proper application design, the fact that the view shows all documents shouldn't be a problem. Personally, I would recommend XPages application design and data + form + view + agent design should be in two separate NSFs. Unless you're accessing attachments or images in rich text fields, you can then prevent URL open on the database and remove all direct URL access. Regardless, Views and Forms can be hidden from web on the Form or View properties. Because XPages runs server-side, the XPages application will still be able to use them.

Comment: Thank you for the answer and the comment. I notice if I use `session.getEffectiveUserName()`, it will return the value like this `CN=XXX/OU=YYY/O=ZZZ`. However in the form, I found it has a reader field and the code is `@Name([CN];@UserName)`. I tried the code and it only returns the XXX part without `CN= ` and `/OU=YYY/O=ZZZ`.

Comment: I am not sure I can create another  NSF. So I may focus to modify the code in the view panel. So in "Filter by category name", can I use `session.getEffectiveUserName()` and then write some code to retrieve the CN part without CN=?

Comment: I intend to use `var leftpart =@Left(session.getEffectiveUserName(),numberOfChars);` and use `@Right(leftpart , numberOfChars)`, but due to the number of characters of each username is different, so is there any way the get the proper  the number of characters of each username?

Comment: I think I found the solution to solve my question in my previous comment.(not sure it is the correct way to do this but it works). In  "Filter by category name", I write the following code `var effectiveuser = session.getEffectiveUserName();
var leftuser = @Left(effectiveuser,"/");
var rightuser = @Right(leftuser,"CN=");
return rightuser;`. Then I run the program use different user account to login, the view display the proper result. Sorry for the inconvenience that I have made and thank you very much for your answer and the comment.

Comment: @Learner Instead of a rather complicated @Left-@Right-combo you should use NotesName to retrieve the common name. Check out the vakuable XPages cheat sheet for more details http://xpagescheatsheet.com/cheatsheet.nsf/url.xsp The cheat sheet will be a great resource for your learning curve ;-)

Comment: @MichaelRuhnau, the cheat sheet is really useful and helpful. Thanks for your sharing!